# How to display random quotes with author name in bold?

Tags: jquery

I got a piece of code that display a random quote from a text file. It´s working fine. However I would like to style the authors name in bold.  The text file "quotes.txt" looks like this:

> Because we're friends, I'm gonna tell you something nobody else knows. I'm   homophobic. Author@
>   Cookies, everyone! Nourishment is most important in the morning. Author@
>   Objection, your Honor. You can't preface your second point with "first of all." Author@
>   Denny Crane. Author@
>   You know what I'm going to do, Brian, just to show you there are no hard feelings? I'm going to sleep with your wife. Author@
>   Did something happen? Was I in the room when it happened? Author@

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('path/to/RandomQuote.txt', function (data) {
            var quotes = data.split("\@");
            var idx = Math.floor(quotes.length * Math.random());
            $('.quotes').html(quotes[idx]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
$('.quotes').html(quotes[idx]);
```

using this,

```
$('.quotes').html(quotes[idx].substring(0,quotes[idx].lastIndexOf('.')) +"<b>"+quotes[idx].substring(quotes[idx].lastIndexOf('.') + 1)+"</b>");
```

Answer (score 1):

LTTP but you can just put raw HTML in the text file. This will give you greater flexibility with styling.